# Would this IOS device test crash be expected

Tags: ios, swift

I am seeing a crash during testing on a real iPhone tethered, pointing to the app delegate line :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

This only occurs if I use these steps :

Launch app on device.

Press home button once.

Double press home button.

Swipe the app up to terminate. [crash] seen in x-code.

I am just wondering if this is expected as I maybe unhooking x-code from the app in a way it does not expect following these steps.

Note: If I skip step 2, and just go right ahead and double press the home button while in the app, to display active apps, my app only resigns, but does not move to background. I can in this case swipe my app up to terminate without seeing a crash in x-code.

Comment: Not sure what you're worrying about here; clearly the app itself isn't crashing since you're manually terminating it. I'd say that Xcode's behaviour when terminating an app during a debugging session probably qualifies as 'undefined'. I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Comment: It's not really a crash if you're terminating the application, is it?

Comment: it is called Xcode. it is nor related to the X-Men.

Comment: add an All Exceptions breakpoint in Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Xcode knows is that the app has terminated. It doesn't know why, and there is no specific place because an exception wasn't thrown. So, all Xcode can do is to show that the main function crashed. This isn't strange, it's to be expected if you terminate the process that the debugger is connected to. Your app also isn't going to the background, it's being forcibly removed from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Dont worry , its expected as you are killing application in debug mode while your device connected to xcode , repeat same steps by disconnecting device  from debug mode you will not get see any issue.